# Jquery - How to select the next element from this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, post, jquery-selectors

I am retrieving 9 image thumbnails from a database, each resides in its own div like so:

```
<div class="post">

<div class="post_desc"></div>
<div class="post_title"></div>
<a href="#" class="linktopost">**<img src="img/thumb.png" class="thumb-img"/>**</a>
<form>
**<input type="hidden" class="postid" value="'.$post_id.'" />**
</form>

</div>
```

Using Jquery I am trying to post the value that is in the hidden input field when the thumbnail is clicked but I am struggling to select it correctly. The value in the input changes with each of the 9 images.

This is how far I have got with the Jquery:

```
$(".thumb-img").click(function(){

    $.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: ##########.val()},
        function(output){
            $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
        }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
            $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
        });

});
```

So how do I correctly select the value in the input field that resides in the same containing class as the image thumbnail?

Comment: Is it .cover-img or .thumb-img ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) instead of `hidden` elements. Remove `hidden` element,and try like this:

*Markup:*

```
<img src="img/thumb.png" class="thumb-img" data-postid="'.$post_id.'"/>
```

*Script:*

```
$(".thumb-img").click(function(){
    $.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: $(this).data('postid')},function(output){
            $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
        }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
            $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".thumb-img").click(function(){
    var postId = $(this).closest(".post").find(".postid").val();
    $.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: postId},
        function(output){
            $("#gotpostid").html(output).show();
        }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
            $("#gotpostid").html(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
        });

});
```

Comment: do you know what is `#gotpostid` and what is the point of maybe `next()` in this question?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Although not relevant to the question, #gotpostid is the div where the output of fullpost.php will be shown. I send the postid and get all the data related to that post sent back to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".linktopost").click(
function(){ var ValueToPost= $(this).next("input").val();

$.post("inc/fullpost.php", {postid: ValueToPost},
    function(output){
        $("#gotpostid").attr('type', 'text').val(output);
    }).fail(function(x,y,z){ 
        $("#gotpostid").val(x + "<br />" + y + "<br />" + z)
});



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

$(yourImage).parent().find('.postid').get(0)

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know if you realised, but instead of selecting a value, what you are doing is in fact setting the value in the #gotpostid element.

To select the value this is the approach:

```
$value = $('#gotpostid').val();
```

If you are setting it then:

```
$('#gotpostid').val($value);
```